# Get error response from ngrx@effects to component

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I need to set server error validation for every input field in form. 
Problem is, I use `ngrx@store` and in effect I have

```
 @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  error$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.UserActionTypes.Error),
    map(
      (error: actions.Error) => {
        new actions.Error(error);
      }
      //this.notificationService.warn(error.error.message)
    )
  );
```

With this code, I store errors to store.

Now I need to get these errors in my component, where I want to check for which input field I get an error, and set error to HTML next to the selected field.

```
    this.errorsMsgs$ = this.store.select(fromStore.UserSelectors.getErrors);
    this.errorsMsgs$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
      for (let err of error) {
        if (err.field === "username") {
          this.usernameError = err.defaultMessage;
        }
        if (err.field === "lastName") {
          this.lastNameError = err.defaultMessage;
        }
        if (err.field === "firstName") {
          this.firstNameError = err.defaultMessage;
        }
        if (err.field === "email") {
          this.emailError = err.defaultMessage;
        }
        if (err.field === "phone") {
          this.phoneError = err.defaultMessage;
        }
        if (err.field === "enabled") {
          this.enabledError = err.defaultMessage;
        }
      }
    });
```

The problem is if I put this code in `ngOnInit`, I get an error in the console because the errors doesn't exist yet.

> ERROR TypeError: error is not iterable

Function for CRUD is in `ngrx@effect` and there is success end error... How to know In component when the submit method have an error response and when I need to call this method in component for errors?

Is there any way to call this method in component from effects?

Here is error response:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-01-14T11:37:51.533+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [{...}
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='user'. Error count: 6",
  "path": "/user/add/"
}
```

Comment: Note that you're not returning anything in `map((error: actions.Error) => { new actions.Error(error); } )` (technically you're returning `undefined`).

Comment: Its ok, because the effect dosen't dispatch new actions on same chanel. `{ dispatch: false }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply subscribe to the `actions` observable chanel, and just filter it the excepted action whit the `ofType()` operator function in the component. Ex: 
`ngOnInit(){ this.actions$.pipe(ofType(action)).subscribe(action => console.log(action.payload)); }`. You need inject the `actions$` observable in the constructor, from `import { Actions} from '@ngrx/effects';`. Or if you want to save this result in the store, just use reducer, and after this select the excepted values from store.

Comment: If you give me a full stackblitz, i can make a simple example for you.

Comment: thnx...this working... and now i get error for every field like i want... but how to remove this errors after reload...they still exist in store

Comment: I need more informations, please provide me a stackblitz.

Comment: i will try, but this app is very very big... i try to made some small part... i will send you  link... thnx